# Prove, using Wronskian, that $e^\left(3x\right)$, $e^\left(2x\right)+x$, $e^\left(x\right)+1$ are linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

I am currently working on a problem that asks to prove, using Wronskian, that $e^\left(3x\right)$, $e^\left(2x\right)+x$, $e^\left(x\right)+1$ are linearly independent.

I went through the general Wronskian process, creating a matrix, differentiating each column, finding the determinants, etc.

I end up with this huge equation that looks something like this:

$(9e^\left(3x\right))$$[(e^\left(2x\right)+x)(e^x)-(e^\left(x\right)+1)(2e^\left(2x\right)+1)]$ ...... $\neq$ 0

Am I expected to simplify this entire equation to prove that it $\neq$ 0?

Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you compute the matrix with an indeterminate $x$, try to substitute $x=0$, and then compute the determinant. If it is $\neq 0$, then clearly the Wronskian does not vanish identically since it is $\neq 0$ for $x=0$.

Answer (score 0):

You should find that the Wronskian is
$$
W=-2\,e^{5\,x}(e^x+3)
$$
Do you see why $W\neq0$?